# Add components to ggplot object saved in list

Tags: r, list, ggplot2, graph

Assume I created a list, with each element containing a saved `ggplot`:

```
lst <- lapply(1:5, function(X) ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x=X, y=mpg)) + geom_point())
```

[image]

<sup>Image of the 5 plots found separately in each `list` element.</sup>

**Is there any way to add additional components to these saved plots?**

I tried:

```
>lst[1] + ggtitle('Add Title')

Error in lst[1] + ggtitle("Title") : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case where the difference between `[[ ]]` and `[ ]` is important:

```
lst <- lapply(1:5, function(X) ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x=X, y=mpg)) + geom_point())

lst[[1]] + ggtitle('Add Title')
```

[image]